# How replace variable values in many text based files

Tags: c#, replace

I need a script/program/whatever to replace specific variable values in many text based files.
I was thinking that regular expression was the keyword, but not so much in to that...

More precise description of the problem:

Original code in a file:

```
POTATO = -3000;
POTATO = 1020;    !this value is updated 2011-08-28
```

Code after "conversion" (5000 added to the variable):

```
POTATO = 2000;
POTATO = 6020;    !this value is updated 2011-08-28
```

**Above is just an down scaled example as the variable POTATO has many diffrent values in many different files...**

Please advise!
Mikkel

Hi All,
Thanx alot for all your posts that lead me to this result that seems to work briliant:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class test
{

    static void Main()
    {
        ShowOutput("TOMATO =-2000");
        ShowOutput("POTATO =-2000");
        ShowOutput("POTATOO = 5000");
        ShowOutput("TOMATO =-2000");
        ShowOutput("POTATO = -2000 'This is a nice value");
        ShowOutput("POTATO =-2000 'This is also a nice value");
    }

    public static void ShowOutput(string InputStreng)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("BEFORE: " + InputStreng);
        Console.WriteLine("AFTER: " + IncrementValues(InputStreng, 1));
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static string IncrementValues(string input, int increment)
    {
        string pattern = @"(?<=POTATO =\s*)(-?\d+)";
        var regex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(pattern,
        System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.Multiline);

        return regex.Replace(input, delegate(Match match)
        {
            long value = Convert.ToInt64(match.Groups[1].Value);
            return (value + 5000).ToString();
        });
    }
 }
```

Now I just need to figure out the hard part - making above code work on textfile.. :)

Cheers!
Mikkel

Comment: my best advice would be to have a database instead of text files so you can do this in the database :)

Comment: Unfortunately that is not an option in this case...

Answer (score 1):

you can use notepad++ "find in files" feature (ctrl h)

you can search for the text `POTATO = -3000; POTATO = 1020; !this value is updated 2011-08-28`

choose the dircetory that has all the files and check "in all sub folders"

and replace with `(5000 added to the variable): POTATO = 2000; POTATO = 6020; !this value is updated 2011-08-28`

Comment: I think I need to deepen... the variable POTATO has MANY diffrent value (possitive and negative) in MANY files...

Comment: Hence, I think a script/program is needed and possibly a regular expression to extract and replace the values...

Answer (score 0):

Using Regular Expression is your key here, Use the `Matchevaluator` delegate to convert every match to `int` or `long`, and then add your `conversion` to that string:

```
private sting IncrementValues(string input, int increment)
{
    //assuming your input is: POTATO = -3000;
    //                        POTATO = 1020;    !this value is updated 2011-08-28";

    string pattern = @"(?<=(^|\s)POTATO = )(-?\d+)(?=;)";

    var regex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(pattern, 
    System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.Multiline);

    return regex.Replace(input, delegate(Match match)
    {
        long value = Convert.ToInt64(match.Groups[1].Value);

        return (value + 5000).ToString();
    });
}
```

result will be:

```
POTATO = 2000;
POTATO = 6020;    !this value is updated 2011-08-28
```

**Edit:** I updated the pattern of search, thanks to @svick to point out a bug in the pattern that was causing the results to swallow spaces after the `=` sign, it was prints `POTATO =2000;` instead of `POTATO = 2000;`

Comment: `[POTATO = ]` matches one character from the characters inside the brackets. It actually matches the space before the number, which is why it is removed in your output.

Comment: No it will not remove it, I tested it, test it yourself before downvoteing!

Comment: Also, what is the `output` parameter for? And you forgot to actually return the result.

Comment: Look at your output, it has `POTATO =2000;`. The space after the `=` is clearly missing.

Comment: There is no use of the `output` parameter, I just add it by mistake, however when you say `Also` that means that you have a first point, what is it?!!

Comment: @Svick this answer is good, you could edit it, but no, you desided to add your won answer then you should downvote others!!, note that your answer is depend on this, your are using the `Regex` and `Matchevaluator`, but a tiny bugs you found make have the right to downvote this, that bug you could of fix in the first place by editing!!!

Comment: I didn't donwvote because of the small bugs. I downvoted because your regex is completely wrong.

Comment: @Svick No it only contains a bug that causes one space not to count so the result is `POTATO =2000;` instead of `POTATO = 2000;`, My eye didn't catch that space that is all, I don't think that that makes the whole answer completely wrong!, Anyway I updated the pattern in the answer to use the first part of your pattern `(?<=^POTATO = )` instead of `[?=POTATO = ]` now.

Comment: What made the answer completely wrong were the square brackets – they match only one character, so the whole `[POTATO = ]` could be replaced just by a space and it would work almost the same way.

Comment: Im a bit rusty in C#, but please tell me what I am doing wrong here:    static void Main()
    {
        string resultat;
        resultat = IncrementValues("POTATO = -3000;",1);
        Console.WriteLine(resultat);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

Comment: @user In the code snippet, you are passing `1` as increment to values, so it will leads the result to be `POTATO = -2999;`, if you want to increment by `5000`, then pass `5000` to `IncrementValues` method instead of `1`, i.e `resultat = IncrementValues("POTATO = -3000;",5000);` will result of `POTATO = 2000;`

Comment: @user Note also if you are running it from `main` then the `IncrementValues` method should be marked as `static`, because the main is a static method, so change the method signature to `private static string IncrementValues(string input, int increment)`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
var re = new Regex(@"(?<=^POTATO = )-?\d+(?=;)", RegexOptions.Multiline);

var result = re.Replace(s, m => (int.Parse(m.Value) + 5000).ToString());
```

This creates a regex that matches optional minus (`-?`) followed by one or more decimal digits (`\d+`), but only when it is preceded by the string `POTATO =` (`(?<=^POTATO = )`) and followed by a semicolon `(?=;)`. Then it uses lambda to convert the matched value to `int`, add 5000 to it and convert it back to `string`.

Comment: You have a bug in the pattern `(?<=^POTATO = )-?\d+(?=;)`:
 the `^` sign will cause the results to be wrong you should remove it, you can test its effect by adding some text into the beginning of the input text, it will not update the first number value.

Comment: I think the results you say are wrong are actually correct. If there is a line `NOT-A-POTATO = 600;`, I think that shouldn't be changed. But the original question is not exactly clear on this.

Comment: No, if the text file contains just extra text or lines before the `POTATO` word, like `This is some foo text POTATO = 1234;` the pattern will not catch it..

Comment: If it contains extra lines, it will catch it. If there is extra text on the same line before `POTATO`, it won't catch it, but I think that's the correct behavior.

Comment: Ok I see your point now... I think then it depends on the format of his file, if the `POTATO` can be in the middle of line.. then the pattern should be `(^|\s)` instead of `^`

Answer (score 0):

RegEx is a good solution for this type of problem. Thought I'd toss in an alternative that uses recursion and strings if you have *RegExPhobia*.

There are a few assumptions here such as the string preceding the integer to update will always be in the same format of `xxxx<space>=<space>value;`. And the value after the variable name is always an integer followed by a semi-colon. If this is not always the case, then the method can be tweaked to accommodate those types scenarios.

```
private void SomeMethod( ... )
{
    string str = GetTextFile( ... ); // read text file into a string

    // 2nd param should include the space before and after the = sign.
    string updated = UpdateValue( str, "potato = ", 5000, 0 );

    UpdateTextFile( ... ); // update the original text file
}

/// <summary>
/// Updates the value of all integer values in a string that
/// are preceeded by the string to <param name="match"></param>.
/// Uses recursion to update all values.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="original">Entire original string.</param>
/// <param name="match">Phrase preceeding the value to update.</param>
/// <param name="increaseBy">Amount to increase the variable by.</param>
/// <param name="startIndex">Index of the original string to start looking
/// for the <param name="match"></param> phrase. Index should always
/// be 0 when calling method for first time. <param name="startIndex"></param> 
/// will be updated automatically through recursion.
/// </param>
private static string UpdateValue( string original, string match, int increaseBy, int startIndex )
{
    string skip = original.Substring( 0, startIndex );
    string fragment = original.Substring( startIndex );

    int start = fragment.IndexOf( match, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase );
    if( start == -1 )
    {
        return original;
    }

    start = start + match.Length;

    int end = fragment.IndexOf( ";", start );

    if( end == -1 )
    {
        return original;
    }

    string left = fragment.Substring( 0, start );

    string right = fragment.Substring( end );

    string value = fragment.Substring( start, end - start );

    int newValue = int.Parse( value ) + increaseBy;

    string str = skip + left + newValue + right;

    return UpdateValue( str, match, increaseBy, startIndex + end );
}
```